# Help returning EDMX Elements

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have a Entity Framework EDMX file and I want to traverse the EntityType elements as well as the child Property elements but I can't figure out how to do it. It always returns an empty set of descendants.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing exactly how the edmx file looks like I would guess that you need to include the XNamespace in the Descendants question, something like:

```
XNamespace xmlns = "http://blablabla.lala.com"

var results = from x in XElement.Load("location of edmx file")
                         .Descendants(xmlns.GetName("EntityType"))
```

like I said...something like this...

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the [Metadata Workspace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387116%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). If you're doing this at runtime you can access the MW from within the ObjectContext (context.MetadataWorkspace). Then you can do things like:

```
metadataWorkspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.CSpace);
```

Otherwise you can load the MetadataWorkspace from the underlying schemas in the EDMX, i.e. the 'Schema' node here:

```
<edmx:StorageModels>
    <Schema ...>
```

using the [MetadataItemCollectionFactory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.design.metadataitemcollectionfactory_methods.aspx)